# How to shuffle elements in a vector randomly

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to do an assignment which requires the following to happen:

1. Request the desired number of elements n.
2. Fill a vector with the elements 0, 1, 2, …, n – 1 and display it to the console.
3. Shuffle the elements randomly and display the new arrangement to the console.

I have the inputting the vector, but I cannot figure out how to shuffle the vector.

Note: I can't use the random_shuffle function or any functions (besides .swap() or indexing in this) so don't say to do that.

What I have so far is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<int> elements;
    int sizeOfVector;
    // size of the vector
    cout << "Please enter the size of the vector: " << endl;
    cin >> sizeOfVector;
    cout << "This is your vector:" << endl;
    // Output each element in the vector
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfVector; ++i) {
        elements.push_back(i);
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So yeah, again, what I can't seem to get is how to shuffle the elements around in different positions WITHOUT using the random_shuffle function

I've tried using the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), but it just repeats the vector:

```
for (int k = 0; k < sizeOfVector; k++)
{
    int r = rand() % sizeOfVector;
    swap(elements[k], elements[r]);
    cout << k << " ";
}
```

**Update**
Thanks to user Danvil, who fixed it.

```
// first shuffle
for (int k = 0; k < sizeOfVector; k++) {
    int r = k + rand() % (sizeOfVector - k); // careful here!
    swap(elements[k], elements[r]);
}

// THEN print
for (int k = 0; k < sizeOfVector; k++) {
    cout << elements[k] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). This was suggested on an answer, but that answer got deleted, so I'm repeating it here. Just about every shuffle implementation I've seen uses this. It is efficient, and unbiased (assuming correct usage of a random number generator).

Comment: I tried using it, and it just repeats the vector.

Comment: You have errors in that code, that's why. I've edited your comment into the question and will answer shortly.

Comment: JBentley, I actually had that and it still just spat it out the correct way, not the randomized way.

I changed the swap function to the more literal approach
    k = r;
    r = rand() % sizeOfVector;

And that worked, but it gave a random number of them.. like it would do 0 3 4 2 3 4 2 1 or it would give 0 1 3 2

Answer (score 7):

Use `std::random_shuffle` defined in `<algorithm>`. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Why would you not want to use this function? Your alternative is copy it's source code and name the function `my_random_shuffle` - but this is obviously silly.

By the way, the algorithm is called [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

**Update**: Your implementation of the algorithm is basically correct, but you need to do it like this:

```
// first shuffle
for (int k = 0; k < sizeOfVector; k++) {
    int r = k + rand() % (sizeOfVector - k); // careful here!
    swap(elements[k], elements[r]);
}

// THEN print
for (int k = 0; k < sizeOfVector; k++) {
    cout << elements[k] << " ";
}
```

Comment: "I can't use the random_shuffle function or any functions (besides .swap() or indexing in this) so don't say to do that."  EDIT: Sorry, you mean to point him to the implementation my bad!

Comment: I would see no reason not to use the function, but the implementation is there to use.

Comment: This is for a course, and the point of the exercise is to figure out how to do it without the function.

Comment: I suggest you read the Wikipedia article linked in my answer. This should give you a hint how to do it. But the result will probably resemble `random_shuffle`.

Comment: Your update helped and fixed it. Thank you and also thanks to JBentley.

Comment: You beat me to it on correcting the random number selection. However, I don't think it's necessary to separate the `cout` statement into its own loop. Each time an element is swapped, it is never moved again after that, so it is fine to print it straight away.

Comment: You are right, but it looks cleaner to me to separate. Another time, another algorithm it may be necessary...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Your current attempt has a couple of mistakes.

For a start, this line:

```
cout << k << " ";
```

Is outputting the index, not the element. You think it is outputting the original, unshuffled vector, but that is just a coincidence due to the fact that you filled the vector with 0, ..., n - 1, which happens to be the same as the vector indexes. Change the line to:

```
cout << elements[k] << " ";
```

Your implementation is also incorrect. In Fisher-Yates, at each iteration you swap the element with one chosen at random amongst all remaining unvisited elements, including the element itself. In your implementation, you are swapping with one chosen at random from the entire vector.

Comment: For anyone wondering why choosing a random item from the *entire* vector on each iteration is wrong, see: [The Danger of Naïveté](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/).