# Function saving random numbers with range to array without repeats

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a problem with a function which should write into the array unrepeatable random numbers from range passed by user. I tried found error, and I realized it must be something with second loop for (counter `j`), I know that it is infinite loop but I don't know why. I know it is a simple exercise, but I really don't have any idea. Thanks guys for help.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int n, from, to, range, random, term;
    int arr[100];
    cout << "Count of numbers" << endl;
    cin >> n; cout << endl;
    cout << "Down range" << endl;
    cin >> from; cout << endl;
    cout << "Up range" << endl;
    cin >> to; cout << endl;

    range = to - from;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        random = (rand() % range) + from;
        term = 1;
        //Check if repeat
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == random) {
                term = 0;
            }
        }
        //Write in to the array
        if (term == 1) {
            arr[i] = random;
        }
        else {
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }
    for (int f = 0; f < n; f++) {
        cout << arr[f] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I tried found error" is very, very far from being a "clear problem statement".

Comment: An easy way to generate a small number of non repeating random numbers is to fill an array with a sequence of numbers then use pairs of random numbers to swap the elements of the array a number of times.

Comment: an alternative way to solve this is to generate all numbers and then shuffle the numbers using Fisher-Yates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850316/how-to-shuffle-elements-in-a-vector-randomly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want non-repeating random numbers in some range you could do it like so:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    int n, from, to; //, range, random, term; // The last three are not used

    cout << "Count of numbers" << endl;
    cin >> n; cout << endl;
    cout << "Down range" << endl;
    cin >> from; cout << endl;
    cout << "Up range" << endl;
    cin >> to; cout << endl;

    std::random_device rd; // Random seed
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // Create a random number geenrator, and seed it
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(from, to); // Define the range

    std::vector<int> ints(1, dis(gen));

    while (ints.size() < n)
    {
        int t = dis(gen);
        if (t != ints.back())
            ints.push_back(t);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I miss read your post. Here is my original answer. If you want *unique* random number in some range you could do it like so:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    int n, from, to; //, range, random, term; // The last three are not used

    cout << "Count of numbers" << endl;
    cin >> n; cout << endl;
    cout << "Down range" << endl;
    cin >> from; cout << endl;
    cout << "Up range" << endl;
    cin >> to; cout << endl;

    std::random_device rd; // Random seed
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // Create a random number geenrator, and seed it
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(from, to); // Define the range

    std::set<int> ints;

    while (ints.size() < n)
    {
        ints.insert(dis(gen));
    }
}
```